# Check a string to not exist in a MySQL table before inserting with Python

Tags: python, mysql, string

I am trying to insert only certain values from a string into table (ie excluding common words) after tokenization in a Python script.

The incoming string might look like "this is a string I want to parse because it mentions IOT". Out of those individual tokens/words, I want to exclude things like "this" "is" "a" "I" "want", etc - but less common tokens like "string" "parse" etc should be kept.

Currently, I plan to have a table of common words I can reference.

While I *could* do something like `INSERT $term$ WHERE NOT IN(SELECT * FROM excludedterm)`, it seems like there should be a simpler method than building a query per term (and, therefore, a separate check to the db on every term).

Is there a Pythonic way to do an equivalent to `NOT IN()...` that SQL supports? Maybe reading the `excludes` table into a list, then comparing tokens against it in some kind of `NOT IN($list$)` format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **preprocess** the data via the the below python snippet.

At the beginning read all the words from the common table and populate the `ignore` list below.

```
inp = "this is a string I want to parse because it mentions IOT"
ignored =  ['this', 'is', 'are', 'a', 'to','it','from']
result = [item for item in inp.split() if item not in ignored]
print(result)
```

Add all the ignored terms to the `ignored` list. Here, we are using list comprehension for calculating `result`. Optionally, we can use `for` loop to achieve the same.

The `result` is the list. Iterate this to insert into your database.